# How to start a rails web app on a vps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a VPS and I need to startup a rails app on it what should I do?

I have CentOS 6.6 + cPanel on my VPS and I need to know where to start.

Comment: I think a good idea would be to start at Server Fault or some other site that actually deals with administration and setup of servers :)

Comment: I may be looking for using capistrano with nginx on a centos or something like that but i need more description about it and if at all this would work